# ncurses:arrows keys not working

Tags: c++, ncurses, arrow-keys

I'm trying to write a snake clone, and I've just begun writing the code, but I have some problems in getting the keypad to work. It seems to not be getting the signal when I click the arrows keys. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

struct Snake{
    int x, y;
    char s = 'O'; // logo
} snake;

int main()
{

    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    keypad(stdscr, true);
    nodelay(stdscr, true);
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_MAGENTA, COLOR_BLACK );
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    int HEIGHT, WIDTH;

    getmaxyx(stdscr, HEIGHT, WIDTH);

    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH-1; x++)
        mvaddch(0, x, '*');

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT-2; y++)
        mvaddch(y, WIDTH-1, '*');

    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH-1; x++)
        mvaddch(HEIGHT-2, x, '*');

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT-2; y++)
        mvaddch(y, 0, '*');


    snake.x = WIDTH/2;
    snake.y = HEIGHT/2;
    mvaddch(snake.y, snake.x, snake.s);
    refresh();


    char key;
    while((key = getch()) != 'q')
    {
        mvaddch(snake.y, snake.x, ' ');
        switch(key)
        {
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            snake.x +=1;    
            break;

        case KEY_LEFT:
            snake.x -=1;    
            break;

        case KEY_UP:
            snake.y -=1;    
            break;

        case KEY_DOWN:
            snake.y +=1; 
            break;
        }

        mvaddch(snake.y, snake.x, snake.s);

        usleep(100000);
        refresh();
    }

    getch();
    erase();
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: You should *always* compile with `-Wall` (at least). Had you done that, the compiler would have warned you that a `char` (`key`) is not big enough to hold the value of the cases `KEY_RIGHT` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `wchar_t` instead char, to store arrow key codes.

Take a look at this: [char vs wchar_t when to use which data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677774/char-vs-wchar-t-when-to-use-which-data-type).

The bottom line in, that `char` is guaranteed enough space for ASCII character set, because its quantity abut to 256 bits. But, Unicode encoding requires more space, than `char` can afford.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is not big enough to hold `KEY_RIGHT`, because it is part of a set of characters beginning ***after*** the range of `char`.

Likewise, `wchar_t` is big enough, but (read the manpage) [`int`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) or [`chtype`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) is the right type for the example given, as the compiler would tell you (when asked).

(`int` and `chtype` are not the same size, either, but for practical purposes, any `int` used by a curses library will fit in an `int`).