# char vs wchar_t when to use which data type

Tags: c++

I want to understand the difference between `char` and `wchar_t` ? I understand that `wchar_t` uses more bytes but can I get a clear cut example to differentiate when I would use `char` vs `wchar_t`

Comment: [Here is the SO thread about this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532785/difference-between-char-and-wchar-t)

Comment: That thread is a bit more MS specific. It might be handy to have this one to get more general "standard C++" answers.

Comment: Some more useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136837/in-c-when-to-use-wchar-and-when-to-use-char)

Comment: International (non english/ASCII) software? What level of answer do You expect?

Comment: International Software please sir

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871880) stack overflow question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fundamentally, use `wchar_t` when the encoding has more symbols than a `char` can contain.

**Background**
The `char` type has enough capacity to hold any character (encoding) in the ASCII character set.

The issue is that many languages require more encodings than the ASCII accounts for.  So, instead of 127 possible encodings, more are needed.  Some languages have more than 256 possible encodings.  A `char` type does not guarantee a range greater than 256.  Thus a new data type is required.

The `wchar_t`, a.k.a. wide characters, provides more room for encodings.

**Summary**
Use `char` data type when the range of encodings is 256 or less, such as ASCII.  Use `wchar_t` when you need the capacity for more than 256.

Prefer Unicode to handle large character sets (such as emojis).

Comment: Does `wchar_t` handle 4-byte emoji?

Comment: Use the following statement to find out:  `std::cout << sizeof(wchar_t) << "\n";`.  If it prints less than 4, then your answer is "no".

Comment: The preferred way to use Unicode is with [`char16_t` and `char32_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types), since they have known sizes and ranges.

Comment: Why the down votes?  This answers the OP's question about when to use `wchar_t` vs. `char`.  The other answers say not to use `wchar_t`, but don't say when to use either.

Comment: @DanielH: If you want to use UTF-16 or UTF-32 specifically, sure. Otherwise, on windows there is a case for using `wchar_t` with UTF-16 when mostly glueing those APIs together. And generally, UTF-8 is even better.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure, if you use APIs which need `wchar_t`, then obviously you should use it. But in most other cases, you should use something of known size and behaviour (and I agree that UTF-8 `char`s are quite often the right choice).

Comment: It's sad to see accepted answer which is misleading. While it's true what you say abount character types, the 'char *' actually supports unicode. It does so though multibyte encodings like UTF-8. This fact basically eliminates the benefit of wchar_t as of Unicode character type.

Answer (score 25):

**Short anwser:**

You should never use `wchar_t` in modern C++, except when interacting with OS-specific APIs (basically use `wchar_t` only to call Windows API functions).

**Long answer:**

Design of standard C++ library implies there is only one way to handle Unicode - by storing UTF-8 encoded strings in char arrays, as almost all functions exist only in char variants (think of `std::exception::what`).

In a C++ program you have two locales:

- Standard C library locale set by `std::setlocale`
- Standard C++ library locale set by `std::locale::global`

Unfortunately, none of them defines behavior of standard functions that open files (like `std::fopen`, `std::fstream::open` etc). Behavior differs between OSes:

- Linux is encoding agnostic, so those function simply pass char string to underlying system call
- On Windows char string is converted to wide string using user specific locale before system call is made

Everything usually works fine on Linux as everyone uses UTF-8 based locales so all user input and arguments passed to `main` functions will be UTF-8 encoded. But you might still need to switch current locales to UTF-8 variants explicitly as by default C++ program starts using default `"C"` locale. At this point, if you only care about Linux and don't need to support Windows, you can use char arrays and `std::string` assuming it is UTF-8 sequences and everything "just works".

Problems appear when you want to support Windows, as there you always have additional 3rd locale: the one set for the current user which can be configured somewhere in "Control Panel". The main issue is that this locale is never a unicode locale, so it is *impossible* to use functions like `std::fopen(const char *)` and `std::fstream::open(const char *)` to open a file using Unicode path. On Windows you will have to use custom wrappers that use non-standard Windows specific functions like `_wfopen`, `std::fstream::open(const wchar_t *)` on Windows. You can check Boost.Nowide (not yet included in Boost) to see how this can be done: http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/

With C++17 you can use `std::filesystem::path` to store file path in a portable way, but it is still broken on Windows:

- Implicit constructor `std::filesystem::path::path(const char *)` uses user-specific locale on MSVC and there is no way to make it use UTF-8. Function `std::filesystem::u8string` should be used to construct path from UTF-8 string, but it is too easy to forget about this and use implicit constructor instead.
- `std::error_category::message(int)` for both error categories returns error description using user-specific encoding.

So what we have on Windows is:

- Standard library functions that open files are broken and should never be used.
- Arguments passed to `main(int, char**)` are broken and should never be used.
- WinAPI functions ending with *A and macros are broken and should never be used.
- `std::filesystem::path` is partially broken and should never be used directly.
- Error categories returned by `std::generic_category` and `std::system_category` are broken and should never be used.

If you need long term solution for a non-trivial project, I would recommend:

- Using Boost.Nowide or implementing similar functionality directly - this fixes broken standard library.
- Re-implementing standard error categories returned by `std::generic_category` and `std::system_category` so that they would always return UTF-8 encoded strings.
- Wrapping `std::filesystem::path` so that new class would always use UTF-8 when converting path to string and string to path.
- Wrapping all required functions from `std::filesystem` so that they would use your path wrapper and your error categories.

Unfortunately, this won't fix issues with other libraries that work with files, but many are broken anyway (do not support unicode).

You can check this link for further explanation: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score 15):

Never use `wchar_t`.

When possible, use (some kind of array of) `char`, such as `std::string`, and ensure that it is encoded in UTF-8.

When you must interface with APIs that don't speak UTF-8, use `char16_t` or `char32_t`. Never use them otherwise; they provide only illusory advantages and encourage faulty code.

Note that there are *plenty* of cases where more than one `char32_t` is required to represent a single user-visible character. OTOH, using UTF-8 with `char` forces you to handle variable width very early.

Comment: Some Windows APIs require `wchar_t`, but on Windows you know that `wchar_t` is 16 bits and have some stability. And `char32_t` *can* represent all Unicode characters, which might be only a subset of what the user considers a character but there are times when it is useful. I agree that a`char16_t` is probably only useful when interfacing with a system that expects UTF-16.